# Azure Data Lake error when inserting a file: The access control list value is invalid

Tags: java, rest, azure-storage, azure-data-lake, bearer-token

We use Azure Data Lake (Gen2) to store files. For the authorization we use a bearer token.

Most call succeed.

But some calls fail with this error:

*Response code 400. The access control list value is invalid*

Some other calls fail with this error:

*Response code: 500. Message: Server encountered an internal error. Please try again after some time.*

Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: I got the same error while using a shared access key for authorization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We got an answer from Microsoft that this was a known issue and that it had been fixed. We don't have this issue anymore.